# Formatting Each Cell with Icons by Cell Above

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to use the icons conditional format to format each cell by the cell above it, if it's above or below.

I'm using the following code:

```
Sub FormatCellswIcons()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Set rRng = Worksheets("Charts").Range("c5:n5")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        With rCell.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = rCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
            .Operator = 7
        End With
        With rCell.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = rCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
            .Operator = 7
        End With
    Next rCell 
End Sub
```

I have two questions, a) why is the subscript out of range? b)Can using the offset within the `.Value` still pull in the value that way?

Comment: What line gives you a subscript out of range? Also -- .Select returns True if the action of selecting succeeded -- not the value in the cell. You probably want to use .Value

Comment: The first `With rCell` throws the subscript (line 7) . also, is there a way to use an address (e.g. =$c$4 instead of a value?)

Comment: I removed the `.Value = rCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select` Select to `.Value` and have it working smoothly now. Now the only part is getting it to do an address without " " marks.

Comment: Well then - presumably rCell.FormatConditions has no elements or, if it does, rCell.FormatConditions().IconCriteria has fewer than 2 elements. Maybe throw in some Debug.Print statements to see what rCell.FromatConditions.Count and rCel.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria.Count are. I am assuming these are collections -- if they are arrays check their ubounds